# grub-install hangs when rescuing a linux install via chroot

Tags: linux, grub, chroot

When attempting to repair a linux bootloader, grub can run into a problem.

Running update-grub leaves the program hanging and never completes sucessfully.

Answer (score 6):

The simple answer to this question is to make sure /run is mounted via bind.

I.e for a chroot to work correctly, the following mounts are required:

```
mount -t proc /proc /mnt/chroot/proc
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/chroot/dev
mount -o bind /sys /mnt/chroot/sys
mount -o bind /run /mnt/chroot/run
```